# Pandas str.extract for np.where: Whitespace outside regex capturing group throws AttributeError

Tags: python, regex, numpy, pandas

From these two strings, I would like to capture the part saying `5X` on the first line, but not the part `X50` in the second line:

```
    "name"
1   LONG YOX 5X AAA
2   LONG YOX50 AAA
```

For a `pandas.DataFrame.loc` operation, I am using `numpy.where` to extract the above parts using `long_keyword` as a locator with `str.extract` for a regular expression:

```
long_keyword = df.loc[df["name"].str.contains("LONG", case=False), "name"]

df.loc[df["name"].str.contains(long_keyword, case=False), "result_column"] = np.where(long_keyword.str.extract(r"\s(\d+X|X\d+)", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip("Xx").str.isdigit(), "+" + long_keyword.str.extract(r"\s(\d+X|X\d+)", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip("Xx") + "00", "+100")
```

When I use the regular expression `\s(\d+X|X\d+)`, I get:

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

But when I use the same regular expression *without* the leading whitespace `\s` outside of the capturing group – i.e. `(\d+X|X\d+)` – I get no error. That would however mean that the part of the string that I didn't want would be included in the capture.

**Q:** How do I fix this error? Is the problem the whitespace `\s` or that I have regex identifiers outside of the capturing group `()`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] which we can run to replicate the problem. Avoid including issues that aren't relevant to the problem. The `df.loc` and `np.where` bits don't look like related to your problem. Your snbtax and use of `np.where`are incorrect. The `sourceString.str.extract` works for me.

Comment: @Goyo I have revised this question and added more accurate detail. Not sure if that changes anything however.

Comment: Your code raises `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` for me whatever the regex is. Anyway you do not expect me to help you debug a line of code 280 characters long with 16 operations/attribute accesses/method calls, do you? And why do you keep posting code that cannot possibly produce the problem you are describing?

Comment: @Goyo I don't expect anything of you, you're the one who replied to my question.

Comment: Sorry, that was ironic. The point is it is not possible to replicate a problem like the one you described with the code you posted, so I am unable to help. I am even unable to tell for sure what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a file like this

```
10,"ABC YOX 5X AAA"
20,"ABC YOX50 AAA"
```

So, the data frame looks like this

```
           string
10  ABC YOX 5X AAA
20   ABC YOX50 AAA
```

And you want this?

```
df['size']=df['string'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
df['interest']=df[df['size']==4]['string'].str.split(" ").str.get(2)
```

The output

```
           string  size interest
10  ABC YOX 5X AAA     4       5X
20   ABC YOX50 AAA     3      NaN
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I have looked at your code but not sure what it's supposed to do. What I want is to take the part of the string `"5X"` and convert it to `"+500"`. I have edited the question to cover more of the original code.

Comment: `"YOX50"` should not be converted to `"+5000"` because there isn't a `\s` before the digit.